# If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep() error message

Tags: r

I have the following data:

```
structure(list(Date = c("1/2/2007", "1/2/2007", "1/2/2007", "1/2/2007", 
"1/2/2007", "1/2/2007"), Time = c("00:00:00", "00:01:00", "00:02:00", 
"00:03:00", "00:04:00", "00:05:00"), Global_active_power = c("0.326", 
"0.326", "0.324", "0.324", "0.322", "0.320"), Global_reactive_power = c("0.128", 
"0.130", "0.132", "0.134", "0.130", "0.126"), Voltage = c("243.150", 
"243.320", "243.510", "243.900", "243.160", "242.290"), Global_intensity = c("1.400", 
"1.400", "1.400", "1.400", "1.400", "1.400"), Sub_metering_1 = c("0.000", 
"0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000"), Sub_metering_2 = c("0.000", 
"0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000"), Sub_metering_3 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), newDate = c("1/2/2007   00:00:00", "1/2/2007   00:01:00", 
"1/2/2007   00:02:00", "1/2/2007   00:03:00", "1/2/2007   00:04:00", 
"1/2/2007   00:05:00")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x000002728b2f1ef0>)
```

When I try to create a new column with the format of date, I get error message:

```
Feb_power$Date <- strptime(paste(Feb_power$Date," ",Feb_power$Time), "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

```
Error in set(x, j = name, value = value) : 
  Supplied 11 items to be assigned to 2880 items of column 'Date'. If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep() to make this intent clear to readers of your code.
```

Does anyone know how I can solve the issue?

Comment: Your code runs without any issues on my machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `" "` in `paste` is unnecessary since `paste` by default has `sep = " "` so it already adds a space. Use `as.POSIXct` instead of `strptime`. (Although using `strptime` would run correctly with a warning).

```
library(data.table)
Feb_power[, Date := as.POSIXct(paste0(Date, Time), format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")]
```